# Update css on value change for a select field

Tags: jquery

Hey my fellow developers, I am learning jquery and have a doubt on performing a simple task, please help me out.

I have a select field which has a default background color as red but I would like to change its backgroud color to white when a user clicks on the field and selects anything other then Select Email Address.

```
<select id="email" style="background-color: red">
  <option value="">Select Email Address</option>
  <option value="abc@example.com">abc@example.com</option>
  <option value="test@example.com">test@example.com</option>
</select>
```

So far I have been able to perform the onclick function but how to insert codition for its value inside it.

```
$('#email').click(function() {
    $('#email').css({
        'background-color': 'white',
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I adivse you to change the event from `.click()` to `.change()` and
try this:

```
$('#email').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() != ''){
       $(this).css({
          'background-color': 'white',
       });
    }
    else{
      $(this).css({
          'background-color': 'red',
       });
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbm86/)

Answer (score 1):

here you go (i'd recommend binding the `.change` event instead of `.click`):

```
$('#email').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length) {
        $('#email').css({
            'background-color': 'white',
        });
    }
});
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

replace the `click()` to the `change()`

```
$('#email').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() != ''){
      $(this).css({'background-color': 'white',
    }
    else {
      $(this).css({'background-color': 'red'});
    }
});
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/w3aBN/2/)

change will only be fired if the value is actually changed, not on click or just open/close

Comment: what if the user selects "select email address" again ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$('#email').change(function () {
    if (this.value != '') {
        $(this).css({'background-color': 'white'});
    } else {
        $(this).css({'background-color': 'red'});
    }
});
```

Demo : [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TgDQw/)